# How to let registered uses edit / maintain own lists in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, list, components, joomla2.5

I am trying to do something like this in Joomla 2.5:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lt2EJ/

This is a NON FUNCTIONAL mockup of course, but in a nutshell, each registered user
needs to be able to maintain a list of items that they have in their collection.

For each item added, the user would select the pattern of the item then write a short
description of the item and then click the `Add (+)` button.

Their list would then update with the latest item(s) they've added.

They should also be able to delete / edit items in their list.

The real kicker is that each user should ONLY be able to see and edit their own items.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Many thanks!

Cynthia

Comment: *"Cynthia must have misunderstood what this site is about."* came to my mind when reading this component request "question".

Comment: If you don't have an answer to my question, don't answer it. No need to be snarky. I am well aware of what this site is about. I modified my question - hopefully it meets with your approval.

Answer (score 0):

you could link it with mysql database connected with database userids for each user to add/pull content (may have to put this in a module/ for joomla)      ,   this link might offer some tips: http://www.alfystudio.com/tutorials/56-creating-and-configuring-basic-joomla-module.html

Comment: I can probably do most of this in external php files and include the results in an articule using an iframe (since the page layout would be using iframes for this particular section anyway). The question is this - how do I a) pull the user's userid from the Joomla database for the purposes of submitting data and b) how do I compare the user's userid so that only that user's data appears?

Comment: You should be able to get current userid with session variables inside of joomla like "$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$user->get('id');"  than use an sql query   --> check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175598/accessing-session-data-outside-joomla , check the following article for how to do an sql query to get matching user data from database in Joomla : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857951/joomla-sql-query